# Extract substring using regular expression in R

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I am new to regular expression and have read http://www.gastonsanchez.com/Handling_and_Processing_Strings_in_R.pdf regex documents. I know similar questions have been posted previously, but I still had a difficult time trying to figuring out my case.

I have a vector of string filenames, try to extract substring, and save as new filenames. The filenames follow the the pattern below:

```
\w_\w_(substring to extract)_\d_\d_Month_Date_Year_Hour_Min_Sec_(AM or PM)
```

For example, ABC_DG_MS-15-0452-268_206_281_12_1_2017_1_53_11_PM, ABC_RE_SP56-01_A_206_281_12_1_2017_1_52_34_AM, the substring will be MS-15-0452-268 and SP56-01_A

I used

```
map(strsplit(filenames, '_'),3)
```

but failed, because the new filenames could have _, too.

I turned to regular expression for advanced matching, and come up with this

```
gsub("^[^\n]+_\\d_\\d_\\d_\\d_(AM | PM)$", "", filenames)
```

still did not get what I needed.

Comment: What yo you actually want to extract here? Please note that `\w` comes down to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` (see the underscore).

Comment: I have updated my post for the targeted substring

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
filenames <- c('ABC_DG_MS-15-0452-268_206_281_12_1_2017_1_53_11_PM', 'ABC_RE_SP56-01_A_206_281_12_1_2017_1_52_34_AM')
gsub('^(?:[^_]+_){2}(.+?)_\\d+.*', '\\1', filenames)
```

Which yields

```
[1] "MS-15-0452-268" "SP56-01_A"
```

---

The pattern here is

```
^             # start of the string
(?:[^_]+_){2} # not _, twice
(.+?)         # anything lazily afterwards
_\\d+         # until there's _\d+
.*            # consume the rest of the string
```

This pattern is replaced by the first captured group and hence the filename in question.

Answer (score 0):

Call me a hack. But if that is guaranteed to be the format of all my strings, then I would just use `strsplit` to hack the name apart, then only keep what I wanted:

```
string <- 'ABC_DG_MS-15-0452-268_206_281_12_1_2017_1_53_11_PM'
string_bits <- strsplit(string, '_')[[1]]
file_name<- string_bits[3]
file_name

[1] "MS-15-0452-268"
```

And if you had a list of many file names, you could remove the explicit `[[1]]` use `sapply()` to get the third element of every one:

```
sapply(string_bits, "[[", 3)
```

Comment: I used map function, but the issue is that the substring could also have _. I could try to use paste function to reconstruct the desired substrings, but sounds complicated.